# Make two foreach statements into one

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following foreach statements, which I want to transfer into linq query.

```
var equalityGroup= new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
var firstGroup = new Dictionary<string, List<string>();
var request = new List<Request>();

foreach(var element in request) 
{
    var key = element.Number;
    if (!equalityGroup.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        equalityGroup.Add(key, new List<string>());
    }

    foreach(var item in firstGroup)
    {
        var query = item.Value.FindAll(y => y ==element.Id);
        if (query.Any())
        {
            equalityGroup[key].AddRange(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone give me a good example for Linq that will work as this foreaches?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what you have tried.  Describe any issues you are having with your current attempt.

Comment: You're performing two separate operations. If you could combine these into one Linq query it would be a lot harder to read than what you already have. And since you're performing operations in addition to just querying it's likely an unnecessary complication.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I will keep this this way. I just thought that maybe there is some kind of better way to do it with linq. I am still new in coding.

Comment: Linq is a querying language/API thats why @ScottHannen suggested it would be better not rewritting it.

Comment: I think we all do this when we learn Linq - we discover that we can convert code into complex, chained-together queries. I made lots of them. Then I had to learn to stop doing that unless it really helped. It didn't help that they added a `ForEach` extension for lists which made it easier to convert `foreach` loops into LINQ statements which did the exact same thing as the `foreach` loop. I used to convert arrays or other collections to lists just so I could use it.

Comment: @ScottHannen `ForEach` on lists isn't really linq.

Comment: @Magnus Then I was twice as wrong. It just looked LINQy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to greatly increase the performance for large collections by performing a join (which uses hash-tables internally) instead of nested loops.

```
var firstGroup = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
var request = new List<Request>();

var q = from element in request
        join y in firstGroup.SelectMany(x => x.Value) on element.Id equals y
        group y by element.Id into g
        select new { g.Key, g };

var equalityGroup = q.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.g.ToList());
```